# Magento2 Wishlist observable subscribe

Tags: magento2, frontend, uicomponent, wishlist

I have this issue with the `wishlist` observable, I try to use the `.subscribe` function on it to check when the observable is changed but I keep getting `wishlistObs is undefined` what am I doing wrong ? this is my latest code, I also tried with `this.wishlistObs` but is still not working

```
    define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data' ], function (ko, $, Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';
return Component.extend({
            initialize: function (config, node) {
                this._super();

                var wishlistObs = customerData.get('wishlist'),
                    wishlist = wishlistObs(),
                    items = wishlist.items,
                    toWishlist = $('.to-wishlist'),
                    nodeRef = node.getAttribute('data-wishlist-ref'),
                    elmClass = 'wishlist-full';

                wishlistObs.subscribe(function (items) {
                    if (items) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                            var product = items[i];

                            var existing = $('.to-wishlist[data-wishlist-ref="'+product.product+'"]');

                            if(existing) {
                                if (!existing.hasClass(elmClass)) {
                                    existing.addClass(elmClass);
                                }
                            }

                            if (nodeRef === product.product && node.classList.contains(elmClass) != 'false') {
                                node.className += " " + elmClass;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: can you share the code before the `return` statement too?

Comment: @subroutines Updated answer

Comment: Have wishlistObs is initialized as ko.observable();

Comment: @Haritha when I console log the wishlistObs , it outputs observable ( because it is from the magento customer data ) , why sould I reinitialize it?

Comment: Please share your full code

Comment: @kunj that is the full code of that script

Comment: try this `customerData.get('wishlist').subscribe(function (items) {if (items) {                   alert("subscribe called");}            });`

Comment: Is that worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

@Vlad Patru Please try below code:

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (ko, $, Component, customerData) {

    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function (config, node) {
            this._super();

            customerData.get('wishlist').subscribe(function (items) {
                if (items) {
                    // Your logic here....
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```